# Umbraco version 7.6.0 - Published page throws 404 in specific scenarios

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am running an instance of Umbraco 7.6.0  and it has started throwing 404 on published pages after some time.

Deleted the AppData folder files and regenerated file and done the deployement but still after few hours site content is going to the older version and pages are giving the 404 error

Need a quick soltion to resolve the issue

Comment: It might help of you described in which specific scenarios it happens.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you checked the log files (/App_Data/Logs)](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/91448-my-website-reverts-back-to-a-previous-version#comment-288647) on the server to see if you see anything strange?

This could be a permission issue.

Umbraco stores its content cache and in memory and on disk (/App_Data/umbraco.config). When the application starts, it will try to read it from this file. So when you have no permissions to update this file, changes are not persisted there. So every time your website restarts, it loads the old version.

You can easily check [if permissions are set correctly](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Fundamentals/Setup/Server-Setup/permissions). Go into the developer section and [find the Health Checks dashboard](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/Health-Check/). Then run the permissions check. This will tell you something is wrong.